# How to make access check to be called once for all languages ​or its result is at least cached for all languages ​at the same time?

Tags: caching, security

I have custom access check for custom entity:

```
   public function access(AccountInterface $account, Route $route, ?EntityInterface $product = NULL) {
    $requirement = $route->getRequirement('_access_product');
    $access_result = AccessResult::forbidden();
    if (!$product instanceof ProductInterface) {
      return $access_result;
    }
    switch ($requirement) {
      case 'edit':
      case 'view':
      case 'delete':
        $access_result = AccessResult::allowedIf($this->isProductOwner($product))
          ->cachePerUser();
        break;
    }
    return $access_result;
  }
```

The method isDeviceOwner calls the external API for validation. The site is multilingual and the language switcher renders an access check for each language, which negatively affects performance. How to make access check to be called once for all languages ​​or its result is at least cached for all languages ​​at the same time?

Comment: You would do that by implementing your own cache layer in `$this->isProductOwner`